# Javascript Toolbar

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adapting a javascript toolbar to a Joomla CMS module. This javascript toolbar has many buttons whereby each buttons invoke a javascript file (plugin)
Current toolbar was done on Javascript.

This is the code to load the toolbar.

Initial code to call the toolbar and its plugins;

```
"undefined"==typeof window.AtKit?(d=document,jf=d.createElement("script"),jf.src="http://domain.com/jw3c/atkit.min.js",jf.type="text/javascript",jf.id="AtKitLib",d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jf),window.AtKitLoaded=function(){var c=null;this.subscribe=function(b){c=b};this.fire=function(b,e){null!=c&&c(b,e)}},window.AtKitLoaded=new AtKitLoaded,window.AtKitLoaded.subscribe(function(){__start()})):__start();
function __start(){var c=window,b=AtKit;$lib=b.lib();var e="ftw resize fonts spellng dictionary insipio-tts readability wordprediction css overlay shortcutkeys tooltip".split(" ");b.importPlugins(e,function(){b.setLogo("http://domain.com/services/logo.jpg");b.setName("JW3C");"undefined"==typeof c.AtKitLanguage?b.setLanguage("en"):b.setLanguage(c.AtKitLanguage);var a;a="Version 1.0.0<p style=\"line-height:120%\">Created by <a href='http://domain.com'>S</a>, <a href='http://www.domain.my/'></a>.<br><br>";
a+="Fugue Icons &copy; <a href='http://www.pinvoke.com'>pinvoke</a> under Creative Commons licence.<br>";a+="Dictionary &copy; <a href='http://en.wiktionary.org'>Wiktionary</a> under Creative Commons licence.<br>";a+="<a href='http://famspam.com/facebox/'>Facebox</a> jQuery plugin &copy; Chris Wanstrath under MIT licence<br>";a+='Portions of the spelling engine &copy; <a href="http://brandonaaron.net">Brandon Aaron</a> under MIT licence.<br>';a+="Word prediction provided by <a href='http://www.aitype.com/'>AIType</a>.<br>";
a+="Text-to-Speech provided by <a href='http://www.acapela-group.com/'>Acapela Group</a>.";a+="</p>";b.setAbout(a);$lib.each(e,function(a,c){b.addPlugin(c)});b.addResetFn("reset-saved",function(){b.clearStorage();null!=typeof localStorage&&localStorage.removeItem("ATBarAutoLoad")});b.addCloseFn("close-saved",function(){null!=typeof localStorage&&localStorage.removeItem("ATBarAutoLoad")});b.render();$lib(".at-btn:first a").focus();null!=typeof localStorage&&localStorage.setItem("ATBarAutoLoad",1)})}
;
```

The full javascript of the toolbar:

https://github.com/AccessAtECS/AtKit/blob/master/atkit/latest/atkit.js

One of the javascript button in the above code calls the following plugin to be included in the toolbar.
http://domain.com/services/jw3c/plugins/tts.js

As per the above code, the toolbar appears on top of my site with all plugins(javascript files).
Right now I dont want the toolbar invoke itself. But need to embed each item of these toolbar plugins into my php file below;

```
    <div id="samsc-<?php echo $module->id?>" class="samsc <?php echo $css; ?>">
    <div class="inner normal-msg">
        <?php echo $text; ?> 
//Need add javascript buttons here
        </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <span class="icon-toogle opened"><?php echo JText::_('TOGGLE_BAR'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are best looking at a non-minified version of the code to see how it works.
There appears to be one for this here:

https://github.com/AccessAtECS/AtKit/blob/master/atkit/latest/atkit.js

I'd imagine from that you should look around lines 94, as that "position:fixed" is what is fixing the bar to the top of your page.

Line 387 would be my guess where it is saying it should render the html next to the opening body tag.

If you don't want to edit this code directly, then it may be simpler (though bulkier) to use css and javascript to modify the display of the bar after it has loaded.  For example, onload you could strip the "position:fixed" style and change the left and top values to match the left and top values of your module.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible I call this JS file in my php and then I call specific buttons on my php instead of loading the whole toolbar?

Comment: It doesn't look like the toolbar has been designed for much bespoke styling out-of-the-box (ideally they would allow you to just send parameters for different versions).  I think you'd have to hack at the code to get it working in that way - I reckon that line 387 could be changed to make the code appear within your own div.

Comment: One further thing to note is that they seem to have stopped updating this toolbar for the last couple of years, and their wiki is now 404ing.  You may be better looking for the features you want elsewhere and coding them individually than relying on all the features of this bar continuing to work.  Scripts for things like the font size increase should be easy to find.

Comment: thanks... Yes. I found several scripts except for screen reader... Thats the reason I stick to this bar.